# Pycharm default tab size

Tags: tabs, pycharm, whitespace, spaces

I am working with a collaborator on a project using Pycharm. I carefully checked each file, and for each, the default was to use spaces, not tabs, with tab size of 4.

However, my collaborator says that on the Bitbucket repository, my branch uses tabsize of 2. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The tab size can be set up in PyCharm in `File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Python` under the category "Tabs and Indents". You will see a box named "Tab size" that you can set to the value of your choice.